# Rails FactoryGirl Error "undefined method `generate' for LoremIpsum:Module (NoMethodError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have installed "lorem-ipsum" gem in my test environment

```
group :development, :test do
gem "lorem-ipsum"
end
```

but I am getting NoMethodError.

Here is my code snippet

```
sequence(:random_string) {|n| "#{LoremIpsum.generate}#{n}" }
```

Any Help?

Comment: did you include lorem-ipsum gem in your Gemfile under the test env?

Comment: yes I have included that

Comment: did you require 'lorem-ipsum' in your helper.rb file?

Comment: I think that is not required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [lorem-ipsum gem](https://github.com/maafy6/lorem-ipsum) you are using doesn't have a class method `generate`, you probably meant to use [lorem-ipsum-me](https://github.com/zachinglis/lorem-ipsum), which does.

**EDIT**
Although that said, you almost certainly don't want to be calling an external API in your tests just to generate a random string (which is what lorem-ipsum-me does).  Why don't you just copy "Lorem Ipsum Blah Blah Blah" into your factory in place of the `LoremIpsum.generate` call, and just leave the `#{n}` to keep the strings unique?